# int works but string::size_type doesn't

Tags: c++, string, int

```
    #include <string>
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    const string& strReverse(const string&);

    int main() {
        cout << strReverse("POT") << endl;
    }

    const string& strReverse(const string& s) {
        static string ret;
        ret = "";


        for(string::size_type i = s.length()-1; i >= 0; --i) {
            ret += s[i];
        }

        return ret;
    }
```

The above code causes the program to crash whenever it's run. If, however, I change the type of `i` to `int` it works.

Why is that? I thought using `string::size_type` was "safer" than using a specific type such as `int`. Using `auto` also causes the program to crash.

I thought that maybe the type in `string::size_type` isn't compatible with array indices, so I tried casting the index `i` to `int`, but that doesn't work either.

Comment: maybe size_type is unsigned, and you are subtracting 0-1 from unsigned which is a huge positive, then you access a bunch of out of bounds memory

Comment: Best way to avoid this issue is to use iterators instead of indices, especially reverse iterators. Better yet, there is std::reverse.

Comment: Aside from thinking about it conceptually, simply using a debugger or even simply adding some diagnostic prints would have answered this question for you.

Comment: Why is `ret` `static`? What benefit did you think that had?

Comment: @underscore_d Because function returns reference

Comment: @Slava Sure, that's a proximal answer, but obviously, I'm really questioning the entire design - i.e. why it returns a reference to a static string instead of just a newly created one by value. Doing so just makes the code look bizarre for no benefit, since it has to clear and rebuild the string every time, so it saves nothing, while being an extreme code smell.

Comment: @underscore_d I do not protect this design, just explaining how one bad decision leads to another.

Comment: @underscore_d It's an exercise, and the exercise asks me to return a `const string&`. I know that I could have used iterators instead, but I didn't understand why `string::size_type` wouldn't work but `int` does, especially since I've learned that using `size_type` is the "safer" way to do it, in general. Thanks for the answers though I understand it now.

Comment: So, another exercise that seems to insist students must do strange things for no apparent reason. I'm glad I taught myself.

Comment: Yeah, I was just doing a couple exercises to get a better feeling for C++, since I have a course related to games, which requires C++. Thanks for the notice though, I'll take these exercises with a salt of grain now (:

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's because `string::size_type` is unsigned, so the for-loop's terminating condition `i >= 0` will always be true. Your choices:

1. Use int;
2. Continue using size_type but change your loop:

   ```
   for(string::size_type i = s.length(); i > 0; --i) {
       ret += s[i-1];
   }
   ```

Or my favoured choice:

3. Use `std::reverse_iterator` and do the whole thing in one line:

Like this:

```
std::string ret(s.rbegin(), s.rend());
```

Some additional comments:

1. Don't return a reference to a static string. It's not thread-safe. Return by value (i.e. return a `std::string`, not a `const std::string&`).
2. For better performance, preallocate the required capacity for the string: `ret.reserve(s.size());`.

Comment: 3. Use range-based `for`

Comment: @Steve Not applicable here, because the loop needs to run in reverse.

Comment: @Slava good catch. My answer here focuses only on the loop. You are quite correct. The function should return a simple `std::string`, not a `const std::string&`. (Actually, it's not a dangling reference because it's a reference to a static, but that also very, very bad.)

Comment: Yea noticed that it is not dangling and removed my comment.

Answer (score 2):

You should pass and return `std::string` by value:

```
std::string strReverse( std::string s)
{
     for( size_t i = 0; i < s.size() / 2; ++i )
         std::swap( s[i], s[s.size()-i-1] );
     return s;
}
```

it would make your function much simpler and more correct at the same time.